# Which event should be applied to the combo-box in prorgress 10.2b, so that it drop down

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Which event should be applied to the combo-box in prorgress 10.2b, so that it drop down. By default, this is the cursor down, but I need it to open by a space, and I just can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it by creating a selection list that's a copy of the list-items in your combo-box.

Here's some code. Assume the combo is called c and the frame is called f. This works even if you have a widget directly under your combo.

```
def var hSL as handle no-undo.  /* Mandatory variable definition in your program */

on ' ' of c do:
    create selection-list hSL
       assign frame      = frame f:handle
              col        = c:col in frame f
              row        = c:row in frame f + 1
              list-items = c:list-items in frame f
              visible    = yes
              sensitive  = true
       triggers:
         on return persistent run piChoose.
         on leave persistent run piLeave.
       end triggers.
    apply 'entry' to hSL.
end.  

procedure piChoose:
   assign c:screen-value in frame f = hSL:Screen-value.
   assign c.
   apply 'leave' to self.
end procedure.

procedure piLeave:
   delete object hSL no-error.
end procedure.
```

Note if you're using list-item-pairs, then the LIST-ITEM-PAIRS attribute should be used where I'm using list-items.

Hope that helps!